# What's the meaning of $_REQUEST['page'] in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

What is the meaning of `$_REQUEST['page']`, and this line

```
$total = $GLOBALS['pager_total_items'][0];
```

in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Phil has given is with respect to the normal php.

In the context of Drupal however they have a different meaning.

In Drupal if you are trying to create a listing with the pager, the `$_REQUEST['page']` is set to signify that it is a pager display, and the value signifies the current page number  you are viewing.

So if you assume that there are 10 items in a every page, you can use something like

```
if($_GET['page']){
    $first_in_this_page = ($_GET['page']*10)+1;
}
```

to get the number of the first item in the page.

And I think `$_GLOBALS['pager_total_items'][0]` can be used in place of 10(that is number of items in a page) However I am not sure about `$_GLOBALS['pager_total_items'][0]`, but I am sure about the first one.

Comment: +1 You're spot on on both accounts. Just check the `pager_query` function in includes/pager.inc :p.

Answer (score 2):

`$_REQUEST['page']` retrieves the value of the "page" item in any of the `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE` super global arrays, whichever provides a *hit* first (in PHP 5.3, order depends on the `request_order` directive).

`$_GLOBALS['pager_total_items'][0]` is referencing a *potential* global variable `$pager_total_items` that appears to be an array. The `[0]` is referring to the first item (or first character if it's a string).

Presumably, these variables are set / populated elsewhere. I can't provide anything relating to the drupal context.